# Managed properties in search schema returns null

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise

I have a custom news template in sitepages in a site collection which I do a "copy" and then publish whenever I want to make a new news article.

However, these news articles managed properties (firstpublisheddate, likescount, comments etc) is null when I extract them from the search schema, even if these properties should have data.

Even if the social bar contains likes or comments it does not show in a search connected to their managed properties.

In the search schema I have mapped (as a example) the CP ows_FirstPublishedDate to the FirstPublishedDate MP. Is there any reason why managed properties from the search schema is null, and is there anything I could try?

Comment: After you mapped the CP to the MP, did you recrawl the content?

Answer (score 0):

Did the issue occur in SharePoint online or SharePoint on-premise?

If the issue occurs in SharePoint online, it runs the full crawl automatically. Then you could wait for a period of time to run crawl in SharePoint online.

If the issue occurs in SharePoint on-premise, then you could run a full crawl in search service application.

Comment: It's on SharePoint online. I did now notice on site contents  (news articles) that the hidden property  firstpublisheddate on news articles is null (and for some reason, sometimes get the correct date). Its very weird. Is it possible to turn on and off this feature?